# Flutter inappwebview get response

Tags: javascript, php, flutter, vue.js

Greeting
i would like to ask:

in web:
window.jsBridge.pushMessage(...)
window.apkClient.appsFlyerEvent(...)

in the javascript/vue.js

and i used codes below but no response:

```
if (!Platform.isAndroid || await AndroidWebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(AndroidWebViewFeature.WEB_MESSAGE_LISTENER)) {
                  await controller.addWebMessageListener(WebMessageListener(
                    // jsObjectName: "window.jsBridge",
                    jsObjectName: "apkClient",
                    onPostMessage: (message, sourceOrigin, isMainFrame, replyProxy) {
                       //do something...
                    },
                  ));
                }
```

want to ask in
flutter webview how to get response above?

Answer (score 0):

use `WebView.platform`

```
final channel = MethodChannel('app.channel.name');

channel.setMethodCallHandler((call) async {
  if (call.method == 'handleMessage') {
    // Handle message from JS
  }
});

webView.loadUrl('javascript:window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler("handleMessage", {message: "Hi"})');
```

Comment: is not working, i can't add Handler in js there.
only can edit in flutter side

Comment: please do it Inside WebView

Comment: inappwebview or webview_flutter plugin?

Comment: do it in inappwebview

Comment: i don't understand the 'javascript:window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler("handleMessage", {message: "Hi"})'
handleMessage and {message: "Hi"} must be hardcoded?

Comment: i ve tried this above
is not receiving any response
would like to know 
final channel = MethodChannel('app.channel.name'); the app.channel.name need refer to which thing?